# Get columns name in dynamodb table with php

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the table name but i need to know all column names for this dynamodb table, i'm using php and laravel.

How to get all columns name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel simply you can write in your controller to get all name of columns like this:

```
$columns = \DB::connection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing("dynamodb");    
return $columns;
```